# Obtain path to image file in XCAssets iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have 2 images stored in Media.XCAssets of an iOS project. However , i dont know how to obtain path to the images stored in Media.XCAssets using Objective-C code.

Please guide

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Images in `xcassets` are not stored as individual images on the device, instead they are composed into a massive sprite sheet for performance reasons.

If you want to be able to get the path to an image in your app, add it to your project outside the `xcassets`, just like you would any other Swift file or resource, and then use `Bundle.main.pathForResource("YourImage", ofType: "png")`

Answer (score 0):

I created a bundle outside the project. Created a folder. Dragged images into that folder and then renamed the folder to have extension as *.bundle. Then I dragged and dropped the same into XCode project.

Now i can access the image with below OBjective-C code

```
NSString *pathtobundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"<bundlename>" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:pathtobundle];
NSString *pathToImage = [bundle pathForResource:@"<imageName>" ofType:@"<ImageType>"];
```